# Como identificar fim da linha em JavaScript / jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
var cont1 = $('.stat_col:contains("Total de páginas impressas")').next();
var cont2 = $('.stat_col:contains("Total de páginas impressas em preto e branco")').next();
var cont3 = $('.stat_col:contains("Total de páginas coloridas impressas")').next();
var cont4 = $('.stat_col:contains("Total de páginas impressas de um só lado")').next();
var cont5 = $('.stat_col:contains("Total de páginas impressas de ambos os lados")').next();
var cont6 = $('.stat_col:contains("Total de atolamentos")').next();
var cont7 = $('.stat_col:contains("Total de separações perdidas")').next();
var cont8 = $('.stat_col:contains("Total de páginas digitalizadas do ADF")').next();
var cont9 = $('.stat_col:contains("Total de páginas digitalizadas de ambos os lados")').next();
var cont10 = $('.stat_col:contains("Total de páginas do vidro do scanner")').next();
var cont11 = $('.stat_col:contains("Total de atolamentos")').next();
var cont12 = $('.stat_col:contains("Total de separações perdidas")').next();
var cont13 = $('.stat_col:contains("Total de cópias")').next();
var cont14 = $('.stat_col:contains("Total de cópias em preto e branco")').next();
$(cont1).append($(" - " + cont1).html());
```

A exemplo o conteúdo do HTML da linha que `cont1` procura é:

```
<tr class="gui-list-tbl-even-row"><td class="stat_col">Total de páginas impressas</td><td class="addrTemp_col">5382</td></tr>
```

O problema que por exemplo o tudo que tem no 'cont1', tem também no 'cont2', 4 e 5.

Preciso além de capturar cada 'contador', poder injetar uma informação (dinâmica) em cada um deles com base no valor correspondente de cada linha.

Answer (score 0):

Talvez você nem precise de regex. Basta buscar por elementos cuja classe é `stat_col`, e usar [`filter`](https://api.jquery.com/filter/) para filtrar esses elementos pelo texto exato:

```js
let cont1 = $('.stat_col').filter(function() {
    return $(this).text() === "Total de páginas impressas";
}).next();
let cont2 = $('.stat_col').filter(function() {
    return $(this).text() === "Total de páginas impressas em preto e branco";
}).next();
console.log(cont1.text()); // 5382
console.log(cont2.text()); // 123
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr class="gui-list-tbl-even-row"><td class="stat_col">Total de páginas impressas em preto e branco</td><td class="addrTemp_col">123</td></tr>
<tr class="gui-list-tbl-even-row"><td class="stat_col">Total de páginas impressas</td><td class="addrTemp_col">5382</td></tr>
</table>
```

Ao fazer a comparação com `===`, estou buscando pelo texto exato. Se você está buscando sempre por textos fixos, usar regex é um exagero.

---

Também é possível fazer as mesmas buscas [sem jQuery](http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/):

```js
function filtrar(texto) {
    return Array.prototype.filter.call(
        document.querySelectorAll('.stat_col'),
        function(node) {
            return node.innerText === texto;
        }
    );
}

let cont1 = filtrar("Total de páginas impressas")[0].nextSibling;
let cont2 = filtrar("Total de páginas impressas em preto e branco")[0].nextSibling;
console.log(cont1.innerText); // 5382
console.log(cont2.innerText); // 123
```

```html
<table>
<tr class="gui-list-tbl-even-row"><td class="stat_col">Total de páginas impressas em preto e branco</td><td class="addrTemp_col">123</td></tr>
<tr class="gui-list-tbl-even-row"><td class="stat_col">Total de páginas impressas</td><td class="addrTemp_col">5382</td></tr>
</table>
```

No caso, [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) retorna um array (não é o mesmo [`filter` do jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/filter/)), então estou pegando somente o primeiro elemento (`[0]`), mas caso possa haver mais de um, basta fazer um `for` neste array e tratar os elementos da maneira que precisar.

Comment: hkotsubo em ambos os casos com e sem jQuery o resultado no console vem Ok, porém no append já da erro pois a variável é um objeto (Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: - [object HTMLTableCellElement]), e vou precisar inserir uma informação em cada linha.

Comment: @DanielPlácido Nos exemplos acima eu pego o texto de cada célula (usando `text()` do jQuery ou `innerText` em JS puro. Se não é isso que vc precisa, basta editar a pergunta e adicionar mais detalhes.